# Saving data on jpa hibernate table gives null on join columns

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two  tables which are related to each other, table "user" and "address":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String user_name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    protected Set<Address> addresses= new HashSet<>();
}
```

While in the other table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Data
public class Address{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    protected User user;

    private String description;
}
```

I did a post request to create new user with some addresses:

```
@PostMapping ("/user/create")
public ResponseEntity post(@RequestBody User user) {
    userService.saveNewUser(user);
     // return
}
```

In a post request I sent this json:

```
{
 
  "user_name": "example",
  "description": "this is a  user description",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "description": "this is a address 1"
    },
    {
      "description": "this is a address 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I insert data I get the "address" table the "user_id" is null, the data are inserted but the relations are not there?
What I'm doing wrong here?  Please help!

Update:  Let's say I have this method saveNewUser on the service, how to call update Address?

```
public Oject saveNewUser(User user ) {
       // 
        return jpaRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Comment: Your json doesn't match with User model specificly address

Comment: You need to set user field in all address instance to sync both side. Like `user.getAddresses().forEach(e -> e.setUser(user));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to support all relations manually. Hibernate doesn't do it for you.
So you need to set a user for each address.

```
public Oject saveNewUser(User user ) {
   user.getAddresses().forEach(address -> address.setUser(user));
   return jpaRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: I added this method but how is supposed to work since I don't call it anywhere?  @v.ladynev

Comment: @xarqt you should call it for each address

Comment: I don't know exactly where should I call it? In the controller or where?

Comment: @xarqt on the service level

Comment: I'm really confused, can you please provide me just a little pseudocode on how you propose to do it? I added a update on my question where I added a service method

Comment: @xarqt I don't know how you are going to add the addresses. You can set  a user for each address, if a user already has the addresses in the `saveNewUser()` method.

Comment: if you see the json body that I sent on the post request, inside the "addresses" I have the description of the addresses, so that I will save on the address, but using jpaRepository.save(user) saves the addresses just the user_id is null?

Comment: @xarqt just set a user for each address

Comment: When I save it I get null on the user_id field, I really don't know what you're suggesting?

Comment: @xarqt okay, I will delete my answer

Comment: please do, because it's just confusing adding a method and not telling me where to call

Comment: @xarqt It is impossible to tell you where to call the method. You have just provided senseless pieces of the code.